# makefile multiple main with wildcard

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I would like to compile many mains that are automatically found in a folder containing many mains.

```
SOURCES       = $(wildcard src/shared/*.cc)
OBJECTS       = $(SOURCES:%.cc/%.o)
MAINS_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/mains/*.cc)
MAINS_OBJECTS = $(MAINS_SOURCES:%.cc=%.o)
PROGRAMS_NAME = $(MAINS_SOURCES:src/mains/%.cc=%)
```

For now I have this code that of course, does not work with more than one main.

```
$(PROGRAMS_NAME):$(OBJECTS) $(MAINS_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LIBS) $(OBJECTS) $(MAINS_OBJECTS) -o $@
```

How could I split `$(MAINS_OBJECTS)` correctly for each main ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of situations [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) are frequently handy:

```
SOURCES       = $(wildcard src/shared/*.cc)
OBJECTS       = $(SOURCES:%.cc/%.o)
MAINS_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/mains/*.cc)
MAINS_OBJECTS = $(MAINS_SOURCES:%.cc=%.o)
PROGRAMS_NAME = $(MAINS_SOURCES:src/mains/%.cc=%)

$(OBJECTS) $(MAINS_OBJECTS): %.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(PROGRAM_NAME): %: src/mains/%.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: `OBJECTS_CXX` are the object files needed to produce the executable.

Comment: It was a poor name choice as I was testing things, I was using `SOURCES_CXX` and `OBJECTS_CXX`, I should have use `MAIN_SOURCES_CXX` and `MAIN_OBJECTS_CXX`. Sorry for the confusion. `MAIN_SOURCES_CXX` and `SOURCES_CXX` have an empty intersection.

Comment: it's perfect ! you can delete those comments whenever you want to ;) thanks !